# How to catch an exception thrown in a JsonConverter attribute?

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2

I'm building a custom JsonConverter to use in an attribute on a model class. The model is used as an input parameter in a Web API controller. In my JsonConverter I'm throwing a `FormatException` if I don't like the input.

Here's part of my model:

```
public class PropertyVM
{
    public string PropertyId { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter( typeof(BoolConverter) )]
    public bool IsIncludedInSearch { get; set; }
}
```

And here's my controller action:

```
[HttpPost, Route("{propertyId}")]
public IHttpActionResult UpdateProperty( string propertyId, [FromBody] PropertyVM property )
{
    bool success;
    try
    {
        property.PropertyId = propertyId;   
        success = _inventoryDAL.UpdateProperty( property );
    }
    catch ( Exception ex ) when 
    ( 
           ex is ArgumentException 
        || ex is ArgumentNullException
        || ex is ArgumentOutOfRangeException
        || ex is FormatException 
        || ex is NullReferenceException
        || ex is OverflowException 
    )
    {
        return BadRequest( ex.Message );
    }

    if ( !success )
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok();
}
```

If I call the controller with a bad value for `IsIncludedInSearch`, I expected to catch the `FormatException` in my controller, but that's not happening. The exception is thrown in my converter, but that happens when the media formatter is running. By the time I get into my controller, the exception has been thrown, but I can't catch it. So I return `OK` even though I got a bad param.

How do I get my controller to see that the converter threw an exception, so that I can return the appropriate response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check the Model state errors which will contain the validation errors and other attribute errors of the model. So you can do something like this in your code:

```
    [HttpPost, Route("{propertyId}")]
    public IHttpActionResult UpdateProperty(string propertyId, 
        [FromBody] PropertyVM property)
    {
        bool success = false;
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                property.PropertyId = propertyId;
                success = _inventoryDAL.UpdateProperty(property);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) //business exception errors
            {
                return BadRequest(ex.Message);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            var errors = ModelState.Select(x => x.Value.Errors)
                                   .Where(y => y.Count > 0)
                                   .ToList();
            return ResponseMessage(
                Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errors));
        }

        if (!success)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok();
    }
```